# One ubuntu machine in LAN cannot access internet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hostname, hosts

I have 4 ubuntu machines connected in a LAN network by a `single switch`.Their IP address is from `192.168.10.10-192.168.10.13`.But after I restarted one of them since disk problem,I find that this machine cannot access internet(others can access internet),but all the 4 machines can be accessed from each other.
I use "`sudo ufw status`" ,it shows `inactive`.

I use "`cat /etc/hosts`" , it shows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
192.168.10.12   mongodb

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

The others have the same config(of cource the LAN ip is different).

So , I really don't know what happened.
I tried to use command "`sudo ifconfig eth0 restart`",it reports:

```
Host name lookup failure


mongodb@mongodb:/var$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:ae:52:c9:61:5f  
          inet addr:192.168.10.12  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d6ae:52ff:fec9:615f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16199 errors:0 dropped:91 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2198421 (2.1 MB)  TX bytes:2664354 (2.6 MB)

mongodb@mongodb:/var$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.10.1

mongodb@mongodb:/var$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ifconfig eth0`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, and `route -n`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thank you.The question has been edited!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a default gateway. Add a default gateway like this:

```
route add default gw 192.168.10.1
```

Replace *192.168.10.1* by your gateway. You should be able to see your gateway using the route command on the known good computers. See my wikiblog [TroubleShooting network](http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/TroubleShooting_network#Do_you_have_a_standard_gateway).

To set your gateway persistent (after reboot) look at /etc/network/interfaces on the known good computers.

Comment: Hi , thank you ,you answer absolutely solved my problems.But I still have some questions.On a good machine(192.168.10.11),I use 'route' command , it show its gateway is 192.168.10.10(which is just ip of on machine in this LAN,this machine has 2 NICs,one has direct access to internet , the other is connected to this LAN switch),but when I run "cat /etc/network/interfaces" ,it says gateway is “192.168.10.1”,why they are different in the same machine(192.168.10.11)?

Comment: First there can be multiple gateways; and I cannot see route's output on here. Second, if the route output differs from the configuration in /etc/network/interfaces there may have been some changes after boot. Third /etc/network/interfaces can contain configs for several network cards, maybe the other gateway is for another network card. Fourth there may be changes by dhcp, but I do not know what happends if dhcp defines another gateway than /etc/network/interfaces. So, first step: reboot and see if it continues working.